ROS2 robot_localization how to correct x and y position when hit a wall
I started using the robot_localization EKF node recently to fuse encoder odometry and IMU data (I'm using a differential robot with 2 wheels). It works well because if I rotate the robot by hand, the odometry rotates too, even if the wheels aren't moving. The only problem is that if the robot hits a wall and stays at the same X and Y coordinates, the filtered odometry shows the robot still moving forward. I think this behavior is due to the filter relying only on the encoders for X and Y. What should I do to correct this error? Maybe using the IMU's acceleration?
This is my ekf.yaml file:
ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:
use_sim_time: false
frequency: 50.0
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false

odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_footprint
world_frame: odom

    #x     , y     , z,
    #roll  , pitch , yaw,
    #vx    , vy    , vz,
    #vroll , vpitch, vyaw,
    #ax    , ay    , az

odom0: /odom/unfiltered
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               true, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false

imu0: /imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              true, false, false]
imu0_queue_size: 10
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true

imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

use_control: false

I already tried to turn some parameters to true but nothung change. I'm trying this because i saw this video where my problem seems to be solved
